# Is it possible to store an image in oracle 11g express edition?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any other datatype that allows an image to be stored into the database?

The list of data types that appears in Oracle 11g express edition is shown in the picture below.

[image]

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BLOB. Not legacy LONG RAW.

Comment: That's the only way to store image inside database. Of course, if you do need image too large for RAW datatype, ignoring legacy LANG RAW, and also BFILE  and SECURE FILES (which is not proposed option above)